# getting special character instead of single quote when writing to HTML file using nodeJS and cheerio

Tags: node.js, html-entities, cheerio

I was just playing around with node, so i wanted to replace the following html in my html file

```
<div class="replace" onclick="opennewtab('one')">
```

Wanted to replace it to

```
<div class="replace" onclick="replacedFunc('12345&')">
```

So i have the following node code:

```
let fs = require('fs'),
cheerio = require('cheerio');

$ = cheerio.load( fs.readFileSync( `${__dirname}/res/writetojs.html` ) );
$('.replace').attr('onclick' , "replacedFunc('12345')");
console.log($.html());
inner_content =  $.html();
fs.writeFileSync( `${__dirname}/res/newwritetojs.html` , inner_content, 'utf8');
```

But what i get is

```
<div class="replace" onclick="replacedFunc(&apos;12345&apos;)">
```

how can i get `'` instead of `&apos;` ??

Comment: how do you send it to the browser? The code you've posted does not do any escaping

Comment: i write it to a html file check edit

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, there something more to it. Here is the test I've done https://jsfiddle.net/mvwf19js/ There no escaped quoted in the browser nor in the index.html file

Comment: Why is the usual XML character escaping a problem for you?

Comment: @usr2564301 i need the output to be `onclick="openPage('APR_18Q2_Ramazan_02_Cevap')"` , currently i get `onclick="openPage(&quot;APR_18Q2_Ramazan_02_Cevap&quot;)"`

Comment: No, you get the common *HTML representation* of what you need. Just like special characters such as `<` and `&` need escaping – nothing unusual about this. (Never mind calling it a "special character"...)

Comment: @usr2564301 thanks for the info , how do i get `'` instead of `&quot;` though

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov check the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cheerio` is decoding HTML Entities by default, when needed you can turn off this feature by passing `decodeEntities: false` option

Here is an example:

```
$ = cheerio.load( fs.readFileSync( `${__dirname}/res/writetojs.html` ), {decodeEntities: false} );
```